# How to programmatically set / edit content of webview

Tags: android

Is there a way I can edit the content either to add to or create from scratch via the java?  I haven't been able to find any examples.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You should look at the WebView documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Among other great bits of information there, you'll find:

```
// OR, you can also load from an HTML string:
String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
webview.loadData(summary, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
// ... although note that there are restrictions on what this HTML can do.
// See the JavaDocs for loadData() and loadDataWithBaseURL() for more info.
```

very close to the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

`WebView.loadData` can be passed a straight HTML string.  I use a "page" i create from scratch in my app that is just formatted with HTML