# How to Align the Text Properly in TextView?

Tags: android, textview, alignment

I have a Textview in which i need to show large information in proper format.How can i achieve it?

I want to display like this:

```
Title  :       Some Title.
Date   :       Date

More Info about the title.
......
......

Contact :      Contact Details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have to do it by calculating the space between the options.

**The better way**

Use a `Webview` make an html string with contents aligned properly using html formattings and load webview and display it.

Comment: I think your are talking about iOS function.

Comment: oops i was...but its applicable there in android also

Comment: set the background color of both the webview  and also html background to clear color

Comment: "background-color: transparent" will do it in the html content background to transparent .Other you can do it via code

Comment: Some user having problem with that.You can see here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003156/android-webview-style-background-colortransparent-ignored-on-android-2-2

Comment: you have the answer there itself ;)

Answer (score 0):

If using a TextView is not essential you can use TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some Title"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some Date"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are three options.

1. If font doesn't matter use android:typeface="monospace" in your textview and align through spaces
2. If font does matter design it in html and use a WebView
3. If you don't want to work with html, you need to make the layout through different TextView's which is imo always better.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, WebView is the option for you. See 
[How to programmatically set / edit content of webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206245/how-to-programmatically-set-edit-content-of-webview)

However, it is possible to do it in a TextView if the text doesn't need special formatting (ex. different color, font sizes) and the only formatting required is indentation.

In layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```

In Activity:

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText("Title  :       Some Title.\nDate  :       Date\n\nMore Info about the title.\n......\n......\n\nContact :      Contact Details.");
```